# Handling Model Inheritance in Django and REST

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to achieve the following model structure:

```
class X(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    objects  = InheritanceManager()
    agroup   = models.ForeignKey(A, related_name="%(class)s_set")
    xfield   = models.CharField()

class A(models.Model):

class Y(X):
    yfield   = models.CharField()

class Z(X):
    zfield   = models.CharField()
```

The first issue is, the Base X class can't be abstract it seems because I need to be able to iterate over all subclasses of X (Y,Y,Y,Z,Z) so I need access to the manager. While X is abstract, X.objects doesn't work.

Second issue is in the REST serializer. I can only reference x_set in ASerializer, as it is the only property that exists on A. And that only display the xfield in the nested list. What I would really like is y_set and z_set on the ASerializer with their respective yfield and zfield displayed.

I can achieve some of this with different configurations (iteration over children by removing abstract, or separation of children in the rest serializer by places the FK field on Y and Z directly), but never all the same time.

Thank you.

Comment: could django-polymorphic help? https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django_polymorphic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Phew!

I stuck with X being abstract, the way to then iterate over X's children:

```
for x_child_class in X.__subclasses__():
    for child in x_child_class.objects.all():
        #Do your stuff
```

And as long as X is abstract, Class A should have y_set and z_set on it, so you can just:

```
class ASerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    y_set = YSerializer(many=True)
    z_set = ZSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = A
```

Trivial, but took a long time for some reason.